# How do I write a value doubling iterator?

Tags: iterator, rust

I want to start with a base value of `1` and then multiply my base value by `2` each iteration up to a defined limit (say the total length of my array).

Do I have to implement a special iterator just to do this? Or can I combine other iterator methods like `map` and `filter` together  in order to achieve the same functionality. Though I would imagine implementing my iterator specifically would be more efficient, but also more verbose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
fn main() {
    for i in (0..).map(|n| 2usize.pow(n)).take(10) { // take(10) so it stops
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
```

It's pretty efficient, there's no need to implement your own iterator for this.

Comment: Where does `2usize` come from?

Comment: @Breedly you need to specify the type of `2`, otherwise you would get a `no method named pow found for type {integer} in the current scope` error.

Comment: @ljedrz Instead of `2.pow(n)` it is also possible to write `1 << n` for power of 2's.

Comment: @kennytm that's true, but I suppose it compiles down to the same thing (bit shift) in the end anyway.

Comment: Instead of `(0..).take(10)`, you could have used `(0..10)` directly.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Iterator::scan`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.scan):

```
use std::iter;

fn main() {
    let items = iter::repeat(()).scan(1i32, |state, _| {
        let current_state = *state;
        *state = current_state * 2;
        Some(current_state)
    });

    println!("{:?}", items.take(10).collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

This has a small state which starts with your initial value (`1i32`) and doubles the state each time, returning the previous one.

---

Since closures capture their environment, you can do this without `scan`, although I like my iterators to contain all the info they need, so I'd be unlikely to actually do this:

```
let mut state = 1;
let items = iter::repeat(()).map(|_| {
    let v = state;
    state *= 2;
    v
});
```

---

And there's always the long-form:

```
struct Doubling {
    value: i32,
}

impl Doubling {
    fn new(value: i32) -> Self {
        Self { value }
    }
}

impl Iterator for Doubling {
    type Item = i32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let val = self.value;
        self.value *= 2;
        Some(val)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let items = Doubling::new(1);
    println!("{:?}", items.take(10).collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```